# Using a populated combobox value to use in a where clause to filter results

Tags: c#

Just another problem.

I am trying to populate a data table with just a combo box when a user selects a crop type.

When the user selects a crop from the dropdown ie wheat, barley and oats for example I want that to be added to a view so return the values in the database.

With the crop selected then it will only show the fields that have that crop planted and the costs associated with it.

```
var select = "SELECT * from fieldCostOverview where CropType = ('" + cmbCrops.SelectedItem.ToString + "')";

//var c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=H:\School\Magee\Project\Programme\Farm Costs\Farm Costs\farmCosts.mdf;Integrated Security=True"); // Your Connection String here
var c = new SqlConnection(@"Data Source=(LocalDB)\MSSQLLocalDB;AttachDbFilename=F:\School\Magee\Project\Programme\Farm Costs\Farm Costs\farmCosts.mdf;Integrated Security=True");
var dataAdapter = new SqlDataAdapter(select, c);

var commandBuilder = new SqlCommandBuilder(dataAdapter);
var ds = new DataSet();
dataAdapter.Fill(ds);
dgFieldDetails.ReadOnly = true;
dgFieldDetails.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

the value in the combo box will then show me only the fields and the details of that crop type.

Any advice or tips?

Comment: can you explain please what is not working please .

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: using cmbCrops.SelectedItem.ToString will give an exception without () at the end. so cmbCrops.SelectedItem.ToString()

Comment: It says invalid column name croptype and wheat 

but wheat is the variable i want to search it by, and croptype is in the table

Answer (score 0):

Use SelectedValue

```
  var select = "SELECT * from fieldCostOverview where CropType = ('" +      cmbCrops.SelecteValue + "')";
```

Comment: Remove the parentheses from your select statement

Comment: Gregg what is parentheses

Comment: () are parentheses

Comment: Even with them removed it gives me this error

An unhandled exception of type 'System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException' occurred in System.Data.dll

Additional information: Invalid column name 'CropType'.